# Layout changes not working in Magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, ce-1.9.2.3

trying to make a very simple change to the category page. Before 1.9.2.3 all I had to do was go into local.xml and add:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>path/to/template.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

I've tried doing the same thing in my local.xml but no change has occured. I then tried in my theme.xml specified xml file and again nothing. I'm not sure why it isn't updating. Here's my current file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/customCategory2col.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

my folder structure:

app / design / frontend / lexel / coffeehit / layout / local.xml

I'm not sure what the cause is... I think it's something to do with the new inheritance setup. However, it just doesn't apply the layout change... I've tried creating a module that uses local.xml to apply updates - nothing. I'm not sure where to even begin to find out how to go about this.. anyone knows what to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `catalog_category_default` generic reference, use `catalog_category_view` (or `catalog_category_layered`, if you use layered navigation)

Apply those changes in your theme layout catalog.xml file

> app/design/frontend/lexel/coffeehit/layout/catalog.xml

If it does not exist, copy/paste their catalog.xml base/default file, and then apply the changes in your theme's file

Comment: I tried that and it still hadn't made a difference :(

Comment: In your theme folder catalog.xml file?

Comment: no, I use local.xml

Comment: Copy catalog.xml base/default file, and paste it in your layout theme folder. Then make changes in that file

Comment: tried and still nothing - I think it gets called correctly but then is overriden by the parent themes

Comment: I think you maybe didn't understood where to place the code. Anyways, your theme (or some extension) maybe has some code overriding layout files, through an observer, for instance

Comment: no I understand, you have 2 fallbacks from your venedor/theme after magento 1.9 - rwd/default which then fallsback to base/default. all customisations should go in /venedor/theme/layout

Comment: Sorry then, you can make this test: disable your custom theme at configuration, apply your change in rwd catalog.xml file & check if it works. If so, then you'd dig into your theme's code, to find where are they forcing the template

Comment: Cause I assume you're refreshing layout cache... Did you?

Comment: good point - will try changing the rwd file to see if it changes come through and cache is disabled but I do clear the cache folder after every save